# [javascript, jQuery]How to wait for the animation to complete entirely before continuing another animation without callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, synchronous

http://jsfiddle.net/jmztZ/

Above is the link to my problem. Let say that I have only 1 div, whose content may change via .html(). I would like to use the div to change its content and display itself using animate() or show() etc. However, when there are 2 functions that manipulate the div, browser's speed is too fast which seems to skip the first .html() function.

Question: How could I wait until the first function (aka "go()" in the fiddle) to completely execute (which includes changing contents .html() and all animation) before firing the second function (aka "went").

Attempts:

*Note: Even though those attempts of mine seems to execute the animation respectively on queue, the html() function can never wait. Take a look at the fiddle again. Also, I've tried several methods found on Stackoverflow, and they all end up the same.*

I've tried using:

```
//Regular way, obviously didn't work
go(); went();
```

And using Deferred:

```
$.Deferred().done(go, went).resolve();
```

And also self-called function:

```
var f = [go, went]; c = 0;
(function selfCall(){
    if (c >= f.length) return;
    f[c].call(); c++;
    selfCall();
})();
```

But none of them seems to work properly.

So to finalize, I would have an Array which can use .push() to push in any number of functions to execute, the functions are all about manipulating the content of the div and animate it. I would like to know the way to properly execute all functions from that Array, one by one, and the next one must wait until the current one is finish.

Comment: You cannot do it without callbacks. That's just the way everything works.

Comment: @Pointy: So is there any way to work around my problem? Like, anyway to push that array of functions into callbacks and force it to work? I've tried $.Callbacks(), but it didn't seem right.

Comment: There are ways to do it, but it always involves managing callbacks. You can have a single callback function that plucks "work list" items out of an array (which is basically what jQuery does for the animation queue).

Comment: That sounds like a new and very good concept to learn for me. May you please post an example based on my problem in the answer part? I would appreciate it much.

Comment: well yes I can post an example but give me a little while; I have other obligations at the moment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
function go() {
    $("#foo").html("GO");
    return $("#foo").show("drop", 750).hide("explode", 500).promise();
}
function going() {
    $("#foo").html("going");
    return $("#foo").show("drop", 750).hide("explode", 500).promise();
}
function gone() {
    $("#foo").html("gone");
    return $("#foo").show("drop", 750).hide("explode", 500).promise();
}
function went() {
    $("#foo").html("WENT");
    return $("#foo").show("drop", 750).hide("explode", 500).promise();
}
var arr = [go, going, gone, went],
    thisItem;

//randomize array
arr = arr.sort((function() { return 0.5 - Math.random();}));

function getNextArrayFn() {
    thisItem = arr.shift();
    thisItem().done(getNextArrayFn);
};
getNextArrayFn();
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jmztZ/31/

Comment: This one is technically using callbacks, which I do not prefer. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why don't you want to use callbacks?

Comment: The reason I can't use callbacks is because I have not yet had any idea which functions will be executed, in which order etc. They are a whole of random functions pushed into an Array. With that, I very appreciate your working methods, but it doesn't seem to apply to me.

Comment: No it does not yet, because I can't tell if the function after go() will be went(). They are all randomly pushed to Array. So if the array is [go, gone, gone, went] then go().done(went) doesn't work quite well.

Comment: Updated one last time.

Comment: Perfectly working. Thanks Mr. Smee. I need to tweak it a bit in my real messy code, but it works now, based on your structure.

Comment: I'm sorry for bothering you again. However, I found this method doesn't work with non-defer functions (as said, regular javascript functions). Can you help me out?

Comment: If the functions are not doing anything asynchronously (Ajax, animations, etc..) then the first function will complete before the second function starts. What exactly are the functions that you are trying to call in order?

Answer (score 1):

You cant do it without callback, but here a work arround. When calling the function, send `selfCall` as parameter:

```
f[c].call(null, selfCall); c++; //null = this in function, but you don't use this.
```

Then, in the go function, do this :

```
function go(callback) {
    $("#foo").html("GO");
    $("#foo").show("drop", 750).hide("explode", 500, callback);
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jmztZ/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think you may try a technic called **Monad** —— But what is **Monad** ? I can not explain it properly.

So , "Please show me the code!"

We have some async functions in a array `pipequeue`,each function in `pipequeue` must be a `deferred` instance . the function can be async. they will executed one by one.

like this : `drop` `explode` `drop2` `explode2` are four async animation process , each one returned a jQuery `promise`.

the complete code is at jsbin: http://jsbin.com/ikovof/2/

```
var $el = $("#foo");
function drop(){
  var defer = Deferred()
    , promise = defer.promise()
  $el.html("GO");
  $el.show("drop",{
    complete:function(){
      defer.resolve();
    }
  },1000)
  return promise;
}

function explode(){
  var defer = Deferred()
    , promise = defer.promise()
  $el.hide("explode",{
    complete:function(){
      defer.resolve();
    }
  },1000)
  return promise;
}

function drop2(){
  var defer = Deferred()
    , promise = defer.promise()
  $el.html("WENT");
  $el.show("drop",{
    complete:function(){
      defer.resolve();
    }
  },1000)
  return promise;
}

function explode2(){
  var defer = Deferred()
    , promise = defer.promise()
  $el.hide("explode",{
    complete:function(){
      defer.resolve();
    }
  },1000)
  return promise;
}

var pipequeue = [drop,explode,drop2]

pipequeue.push(explode2);

pipe(unit(),pipequeue);
```

You can `push` or `pop` `pipequeue` . every fn in `pipequeue` is without coupling ！

But if you think `pipe(unit(),pipequeue)` is a bit of ...

you can wrap `unit()` call into a function:

```
function pipePromise(pipequeue){
  pipe(unit(),pipequeue);
}
// then your call can be quite neat now  
pipePromise(pipequeue);
```

Answer (score 0):

I like [Mr. Smee's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17768869/361684), but there is another option.  Write the html in a callback to `.hide(0, callback)`:

```
$("#foo").hide(0, function(){ $(this).html("GO"); });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jmztZ/34/

You can even call them sequentially that way:

http://jsfiddle.net/jmztZ/35/